# Why std::thread accepts generic lambdas but not templated functions (without explicit instantiation)?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, stdthread

Why is it legal to pass generic lambdas to std::thread() without any specialization, while, on the other hand, this is illegal with function templates.

The following demonstrates my query.

```cpp
#include <thread>

template <class T>
void f(T t)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t([](auto i){}, 1);  // Works
    std::thread t(f, 1);          // Doesn't work
    std::thread t(f<int>, 1);     // Works

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since deduction type can't be done based on internal implementation. It happens based on function (here constructor) arguments. Now lambda is instance of specific type with function which is a template. Take a look on this: https://cppinsights.io/s/e0e75c1c

Comment: @MarekR could you please elaborate...

Comment: A template function is just a template, a blueprint for a function, but it's not an actual function. You need to say which explicit function you want to use. A lambda, even a generic one like you have, is not a template. It's an actual object with a specific function-call operator overload.

Comment: Again generic lambda is a solid type (see https://cppinsights.io/s/e0e75c1c). So not a template is passed to thread, but object with well defined type. Then when lambda is invoked there is attempt to instantiate member function template which is `operator()(auto)`.

Comment: A lambda is effectively an instance of a compiler-defined type with an `operator()` on it. So, `std::thread t([](auto i){}, 1);` is basically like: `struct <generated> { void operator()(auto i){} }; <generated> instance; std::thread t(instance, 1);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ consists of many different kinds of things. Some of these things are: objecs, types, and templates. They are completely different things, that serve their own distinct, unique purposes. There's a right place in a C++ program to use an object, a right place to use a type, and a right place to use a template. When you have a right place for an object, you can't use a type or a template. When you have a right place to use a type you can't use an object or a template. When you have a right place to use a template you can't use an object or a type. This is fundamental to C++.

The parameters to a function call, or a constructor, are always objects. They are never types, or templates.

```
    std::thread t([](auto i){}, 1);  // Works
```

Both parameters are objects. This is correct. A lambda is an object, an instance of a unique, anonymous type. `1` is also an object: an integer whose value is 1.

```
    std::thread t(f, 1);          // Doesn't work
```

`f` is not an object. It is a template.

```
    std::thread t(f<int>, 1);     // Works
```

This `f<int>` is an object, a pointer to a function that was instantiated from a template.

An identifier that corresponds to a name of a template, by itself, results in a template. It does not result in a type, or an object. When you specify template parameters you end up with a type, and in a special case of a type that refers to a template function you get a pointer to the template function instance, an object (just like using the name of an ordinary non-template function, by itself, gives you a pointer to that function).